# How to use .split with new lines in a 2d array Java Android

Tags: java, android, java-io

I have a .txt file, in my assets folder which reads something like this:

I love life ;
We all dance ;
Too much pizza ;

I want to store each one of these elements into a String[] which is declared in my graphics file.

The code in my main as of right now reads

```
AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream is=null;

try {
    is = am.open("b.txt");
    InputStreamReader bFile= new InputStreamReader((is),"UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(bFile);
    ArrayList<String> bPlaceHold= new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] bPlace2;
    String line= br.readLine();
    graphics.doing=0;                   

    while(line !=null)
    {
        bPlace2= line.split(";\n");
        bPlaceHold.add(line);
        line=br.readLine();
        graphics.doing++;           
        graphics.tester[graphics.doing]=bPlaceHold.get(graphics.doing);
    }

    br.close();
    bFile.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've read everything I could find relating to the topic but no matter what method i try only the very first line from the file is displaying and it crashes once it trys to .get(1); Any help would be greatly appreciated I'm new to all the formalities involved in android/java programming

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this :

```
graphics.tester[graphics.doing]=bPlaceHold.get(graphics.doing-1);
```

Reason : You are actually storing value of line at index 0 and trying to fetch the value of index one which throws you an exception. Hope this will clear your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding whole string instead of splited one.

```
bPlaceHold.add(bPlace2[0]);
```

try like this instead of

```
bPlaceHold.add(line);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried your method and it reads out true, I also tried .add(bPlace2[0]) with .add(bPlace2[graphics.doing]) and it makes it just crash. Am I missing a convertion somewhere?